# How can I make my c++ code run faster with eigen library?

Tags: c++, c++11, eigen

I have written a parallelized c++ code, which functions as follows :

1. There are 75 'w' points, and each of them is sent to one processor.
2. For each 'w' point, I am defining a matrix. Then I am diagonalizing it. I am using the eigenvectors to compute a particular quantity by summing over the fourth power of each of the matrix elements. And then I average this quantity over 300 iterations of the matrix.

So I am using Eigen package for this calculation, and I compile the code with mpiCC -I eigen -Ofast filename.cpp. For a 512 x 512 matrix, the whole procedure takes 2.5 hours. Currently I need to do the same for a 2748 x 2748 matrix, and it's still going on after approx. 12:30 hrs. Is there anyway I can make the code run faster?

The code is given here for reference :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>
#include <cmath>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<Eigen/Dense>
#include<fstream>
#include<random>
#include "mpi.h"

#define pi 3.14159

using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;


#define no_of_processor 75 // no of processors used for computing 
#define no_of_disorder_av 300 //300 iterations for each w
#define A_ratio    1      //aspect ratio Ly/Lx
#define Lx        8
#define w_init    0.1    // initial value of potential strength 
#define del_w     0.036    // increment of w in each loop
#define w_loop     75      // no of different w
#define alpha    (sqrt(5.0)-1.0)/(double)2.0

double onsite_pot(int x,int y, int z, double phi, double alpha_0){

 double B11=alpha;
 double B12=alpha;
 double B13=alpha;
 double b1= (double)B11*x+(double)B12*y+(double)B13*z;
 double c11= 1.0-cos(2*M_PI*b1+phi); //printf("%f\n",c1);
 double c12= 1.0+(alpha_0*cos(2*M_PI*b1+phi));
 double c1=c11/c12;

 return c1;
 }

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
clock_t begin = clock();

/*golden ratio----------------------------*/

char filename[200];
double t=1.0;
int i,j,k,l,m;//for loops
double alpha_0=0;

int Ly=A_ratio*Lx;
int Lz= A_ratio*Lx;
int A=Lx*Ly;
int V=A*Lz; //size of the matrix   

int numtasks,rank,RC;
RC=MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
if (RC != 0) {
 printf ("Error starting MPI program. Terminating.\n");
 MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, RC);
 }
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&numtasks);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);

sprintf(filename,"IPR3D%dalpha%g.dat",rank+1,alpha_0);
ofstream myfile;
myfile.open(filename, ios::app); //preparing file to write in

int n = w_loop/no_of_processor;
double w=w_init+(double)(n*rank*del_w);
int var_w_loop = 0;
MatrixXcd H(V,V); // matrix getting defined here
MatrixXcd evec(V,V); // matrix for eigenvector
VectorXcd temp(V); // vector for a temporary space used later in calculation
double IPR[V], E_levels[V]; // for average value of the quantity and eigen values.

do{
for(i=0;i<V;i++)
 {
   IPR[i]=E_levels[i]=0.0;
 }

/*!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!*/
/*!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!*/
/*----loop for disorder average---------------------------*/
for (l=0;l<no_of_disorder_av;l++){

 for (i=V; i<V; i++)
 { 
  for (j=V; j<V; j++)
      H(i,j)=0;
 }
double  phi=(2*M_PI*(double)l)/(double)no_of_disorder_av;
//matrix assignment starts
int z=0; 
for (int plane=0; plane<Lz; plane++)
 {
  z += 1 ;
  int y=0;
  int indx1= plane*A  ;  //initial index of each plane
  int indx2= indx1+A-1;  // last index of each plane
  for (int linchain=0; linchain<Ly; linchain++){
      y += 1;
      int x=0;
      int indx3= indx1 + linchain*Lx ;  //initial index of each chain
      int indx4= indx3 + Lx-1  ;  //last index of each chain
      for (int latpoint=0; latpoint<Lx; latpoint++){
          x += 1;
          int indx5= indx3 +latpoint;  //index of each lattice point
          H(indx5,indx5)= 2*w*onsite_pot(x,y,z,phi,alpha_0);  //onsite potential
          if (indx5<indx4){    //hopping inside a chain
             H(indx5,(indx5+1))= t; //printf("%d %d\n",indx5,indx5+1);
             H((indx5+1),indx5)= t;
             }
          if (indx5<=(indx2-Lx)){  //hopping between different chain
             H(indx5,(indx5+Lx))= t; //printf("%d %d\n",indx5,indx5+Lx);
             H((indx5+Lx),indx5)= t;
             printf("%d\n",indx5);
             }
          if (indx5<(V-A)){
             H(indx5,(indx5+A))= t;   //printf("%d %d\n",indx5,indx5+A);// hopping between different plane
             H((indx5+A),indx5)= t;
             }                 
         } //latpoint loop
     }//linchain loop
  }//plane loop


  //PB..............................................
  for (int plane=0; plane<Lz; plane++){
  int indx1= plane*A;  //initial index of each plane
  int indx2 = indx1+A-1 ;//last indx of each plane
  //periodic boundary condition x
    for (int linchain=0; linchain<Ly; linchain++){
    int indx3 = indx1 + linchain*Lx;   // initital index of each chain
    int indx4=indx3+ Lx-1;          //last index of each chain
    H(indx3,indx4)= t; //printf("%d %d\n",indx3,indx4);
    H(indx4,indx3)= t;
     }//linchain loop
 //periodic boundary condition y
    for (int i=0; i<Lx; i++){
    int indx5 = indx1+i;
    int indx6 = indx5+(Ly-1)*Lx;  //printf("%d %d\n",indx5,indx6);
    H(indx5,indx6)=t;
    H(indx6,indx5)=t;
   }
   }//plane loop

 //periodic boundary condition in z
 for (int i=0; i<A; i++){
 int indx1=i ;
 int indx2=(Lz-1)*A+i ;
 H(indx1,indx2)= t; //printf("%d %d\n",indx1,indx2);
 H(indx2,indx1)= t ; 
 }
//matrix assignment ends
/**-------------------------------------------------------*/
double Tr = abs(H.trace());
for(i=0;i<V;i++)
  {
    for(j=0;j<V;j++)
    {
      if(i==j)
      {
      H(i,j) = H(i,j)-(Tr/(double)V);
      }
    }
  }

  SelfAdjointEigenSolver<MatrixXcd> es(H); //defining the diagonalizing function
   double *E = NULL; 
   E = new double[V]; // for the eigenvalues
   for(i=0;i<V;i++)
    {
     E[i]=es.eigenvalues()[i];
     //cout<<"original eigenvalues "<<E[i]<<"\n";
    }
   evec=es.eigenvectors();
   double bandwidth = E[V-1] - E[0];
   for(i=0;i<V;i++)
   E[i]=E[i]/bandwidth;

   for(i=0;i<V;i++)
    {
     E_levels[i] = E_levels[i]+E[i]; //summing over energies for each iteration
    }

   delete[] E;
   E=NULL;
   //main calculation process
   for(i=0;i<V;i++)
   {
     temp = evec.col(i);
     double num=0.0,denom=0.0; 
     for(j=0;j<V;j++)
      {
       num=num+pow(abs(temp(j)),4);
       denom=denom+pow(abs(temp(j)),2);
      }
     IPR[i] = IPR[i]+(num/(denom*denom)); 
   } //calculation ends
   }//no_of_disorder_av loop (l)
   for(i=0; i<V; i++)
  {
    myfile<<w<<"\t"<<(E_levels[i]/(double)no_of_disorder_av)<<"\t" 
    <<(IPR[i]/(double)no_of_disorder_av)<<"\n"; //taking output in file
  }
  var_w_loop++; // counts number of w loop
  w+= del_w; // proceeds to next w

  }while(var_w_loop<n) ;    // w varying do while loop

  MPI_Finalize();

  clock_t end = clock();
  double time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
  printf("time spent %f s\n\n",time_spent);

  return 0;
 }
```

Comment: A triple-nested `for` loop is a bad omen for slow code, regardless of what the program is supposed to do.

Comment: So I have a 14^3 x 14^3 matrix (a Hamiltonian matrix for a 3D lattice system of 14 x 14 x 14 dimensions), I diagonalise it and obtain 14^3 eigenvalues and eigenvectors. For each of the eigenvectors, I have to sum over the fourth power of the elements and then average it over 300 iterations of a certain variable (labelled as phi here) and plot it against the average eigenvalues of the matrix.

Comment: Did you benchmark your code? What parts take the most time? How often do you need to compute eigenvector-decompositions? If you reduce your code to the part which takes the most time (and clean up the formatting), you may have better chances of someone helping you.

Comment: I second the need for benchmarks. Measure first. I also recommend to split your code in several function. Use const as often as you can. Consider using constexpr instead of define and for most of your parameter.. Also consider to restructure your loops. You will most likely get cache misses if you update by changing different rows an columns at the same time. Consider using smart pointers instead of this raw delete[] . Better use std array since V is known at compile time. This code is full of opportunities for improvement

Comment: @Mehno In almost all cases `new double[n]`/`delete[]` should be replaced by a `std::vector<double>`, in this case it should even be just `Eigen::VectorXd`. But I agree, there is so much more wrong with this code ...

Comment: If you need hints on cleaning up this code, perhaps try [codereview.se].

Comment: @chtz except if n is known at compile time. In all other cases, i agree

Comment: @Mehno Yes, if `n` is known at compile time use `std::array<double,n>` or `Eigen::Matrix<double,n,1>`, of course.

Comment: In this example it is known at compile time as far as i can tell

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I will take a look at the link provided by @chtz.

Comment: In the loop where you subtract the trace from the diagonal entries can be substituted with a single line: `H.diagonal().array() -= (Tr/(double)V);`